# $f=g\; ; \;\bar{\mu}$-a.e. vs $\mu$-a.e.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu )$ be a measure space and let $(X,\overline{\mathcal{M}},\overline{\mu})$ be its completion. Let $f,g$ be in the set of the union of $\mathcal{M}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable functions.

It seems to me that $f=g$ a.e. is the same for both $\mu$-a.e. and $\overline{\mu}$-a.e. My textbook Folland likes to write $f=g$ $\overline{\mu}$-a.e., is there any reason to differentiate between them?

I'm using the definition that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. if there exists an $N\in \cal{M}$ such that $ \{ x: f(x) \ne g(x) \} \subset N$ and $\mu(N)=0$. Maybe sometimes people use other definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a remark, since it is easier to be $\overline {\mathcal M}$-measurable, $ {\mathcal M}|\mathscr B(\Bbb R)\cup\overline {\mathcal M}|\mathscr B(\Bbb R) = \overline {\mathcal M}|\mathscr B(\Bbb R)$. Now, it depends how you define that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. If this is defined by $\mu(f\neq g) = 0$ then it is a stronger condition than the one $\bar\mu(f \neq g) = 0$ since in the former case the set $\{f\neq g\}$ has to be in $\mathcal M$, whereas in the latter it can belong to a larger class of sets.

Instead, if the definition is

> $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. if and only if $\{f\neq g\}\subseteq A$ for some $A$ s.t. $\mu(A) = 0$

then there is no difference between $\mu$-a.e. and $\bar\mu$-a.e.

Comment: Could you give an example of where it's needed to use the $\mu(f \ne g) = 0$ definition? Obviously it's not useful for integration theory (what I'm studying), but I'd be interested in knowing where it's useful.

Comment: @Stuart: I didn't get your point. See also my edit, does it clarify the thing?

Comment: You're saying that if we use another definition, then the statement is false. My question is whether this alternate definition is ever used in practice? That is, could you point to an theorem where this alternate definition is used, but my given definition wouldn't work?

Comment: @Stuart: I see your point. Since you didn't provide the definition from the start, I have doubts which one of the you mean. The alternate one I saw in some Russian books at least. For the definition you use, I wrote already, there is no difference. Is it clear now?